# .init is not a function using opus-recorder

Tags: audio, web-audio-api, encoder, ogg, opus

I'm programing a react app that has a integration with the what's app api. To be able to send voice messages, I need to get a .ogg codecs=opus or .opus audio file format from my browser, I'm trying to use the library opus-coder for it.

As far I can see, I'm using the library correctly, but receiving "TypeError: recorder.current.init is not a function". Has been two days since I'm struggling to be able to send voice messages, please someone who know's better this field show what I need to do, i feel is something not that hard.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
import Recorder from "opus-recorder";
import encoderPath from "opus-recorder/dist/encoderWorker.min.js";

const recorder = useRef(null);

const startRecording = () => {
    // Verifica se o navegador suporta getUserMedia
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      // Solicita permissão para acessar o microfone
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
        .then(async (stream) => {
          // Cria uma instância do Recorder
          recorder.current = new Recorder({
            encoderPath: encoderPath, // Caminho para o arquivo do worker do encoder
            leaveStreamOpen: true, // Manter a stream de áudio aberta após a gravação
            encoderSampleRate: 48000, // Taxa de amostragem do encoder (padrão: 48000)
            encoderApplication: 2049, // Aplicação de codificação do encoder (padrão: 2049)
          });

          console.log(recorder.current);
          // Inicia a gravação
          await recorder.current.init(stream);
          await recorder.current.start();

          console.log("Gravação iniciada...");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Erro ao acessar a mídia:", error);
        });
    }
  };

  const stopRecording = async () => {
    // Verifica se existe um recorder em execução
    if (recorder.current) {
      // Para a gravação
      await recorder.current.stop();

      console.log("Gravação encerrada...");

      // Obtém o áudio gravado
      const audioData = await recorder.current.exportWAV();
      const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioData);

      // Cria um link para fazer o download do áudio
      const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
      downloadLink.href = audioUrl;
      downloadLink.download = "teste.opus";
      document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
      downloadLink.click();
      document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);

      console.log(audioUrl);
      recorder.current.close();
    }
  };
```